# Can you do something like RoutePrefix with parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I am wondering if I can do something like `RoutePrefix("{projectName}/usergroups")` because I have many projects and each project contains usergroups. Now in every `Usergroup` controller I will first need to get the `Project` that it's tied to. Is this possible?

#### What have I tried

I tried simply to do `RoutePrefix("projects/{projectName}")` and then pass it in controller constructor but it does not work like that. I also tried to use `Route` instead of `RoutePrefix` on controller level but then my routes inside do not work.

#### Code

```
[RoutePrefix("projects"), Authorization]
public class UsergroupController : Controller
{
    private readonly Project _project; // i would like to inject it here on constructor
    private readonly Account _account;
    private readonly IProjectRepository _projectRepository;

    public UsergroupController(IAuthorizationService auth, IProjectRepository projectRepository)
    {
        _projectRepository = projectRepository;
        _account = auth.GetCurrentAccount();
    }

    [Route("{projectName}/usergroups"), HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string projectName)
    {
        // the problem that i will need to pass projectName
        // to every action and do this check in every action as well
        //
        // looks like totally ugly code-duplication
        var project = _projectRepository
            .GetByAccountId(_account.Id.ToString())
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == projectName);

        if (project == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        // now get all usergroups in this project e.g. project.Usergroups

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can have a route prefix that takes parameters, but your action methods still have to accept the parameter just as if it was part of their route. You can't satisfy the dependency from the constructor of your controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("{projectName}/usergroups")]
public class UsergroupController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult Index(string projectName)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey, well I *could* do this within controller construction with DI that would gather route info from Url but I don't think that it would be the best way. Too complicated.

Comment: Custom attributes might be something in-between?